# QT Creator - QStackedWidget pages proglem

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I started new project in Qt Creator (Qt Widget Project > Qt Gui Application) and I can't make stacked widget work properly.

I don't know how to change pages in stacked widget which I added using `ui`. Program object structure looks like this:

```
MainWindow(QMainWindow)
 > centralWidget(QCentralWidget)
  > mainStackedWidget(QStackedWidget)
```

and `mainStackedWidget` has page1, page2, page3.

I tried few things but I failed.

Basically all my tries were to somehow use `mainStackedWidget` in `main.cpp` but I didn't manage to figure out how to use object, created in `ui`, in `main.cpp`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the code you're trying to use (and clear explanations of why it's not working/compiler errors/etc.), this is simple not answerable. (Apart from pointing you to docs/tutorials.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you want is `QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex()` or `QStackedWidget::setCurrentWidget()`.

If you did not use Qt Designer, just use:

```
mainStackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

If you did use Qt Designer, you would probably use:

```
ui->mainStackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I was editing main.cpp file instead of mainwindow.cpp.